# How can I use ruby build tools in a php app and deploy to heroku?

Tags: heroku

Currently, heroku assumes my app is a ruby app because it has a Gemfile. But I just want to use compass/foundation in my build process, and have a Gemfile so that things are versioned in a standard way. The app is a static site, so I want heroku to run it on the php stack (which works fine if I remove my Gemfile).

Answer (score 1):

You can override the default buildpack resolution like this

```
heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php
```

See the [documentation on using custom buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#using-a-custom-buildpack) for details.